# QWidget is not updating when using show instead of exec

Tags: qt, qt4, qwidget, qt-mfc-migration

In my project, I need to create a non-blocking QWizard on the top of my Mfc application.  To do this, I followed the instruction here ([link](http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/winmigrate-walkthrough.html#a-new-qt-dialog))

Doing this have a strange side-effect, it looks like that my UI is not updating properly when I am clicking my QRadioButton inside my QWizardPage.  See following screenshots :

*1-First step in my QWizard. Everything looks good*

[image: First step in my QWizard. Everything looks good]

*2-I clicked on a QRadioButton.  See, the "Next" button is in a weird state.*

[image: I clicked on a QRadioButton. See, the "Next" button is in a weird state.]

*3-I clicked on the second QRadioButton. See, both QRadioButton look selected.  (Yes, they are mutually exclusive!*

[image: I clicked on the second QRadioButton. See, both QRadioButton look selected. (Yes, they are mutually exclusive!)]

*4-Now, if I am doing a "mouse over", over the "Next" button and over QRadioButton, this forces an update and my UI is fine*

[image: Now, if I am doing a "mouse over", over the "Next" button and over QRadioButton, that forces an update and my UI is fine]

My question is : How to update properly my UI when using show instead of exec? (I did try with exec and my UI is updating properly)

I guess that main thread is not updating my UI if I use show?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

Here is the code of the function that instantiate the wizard :

```
void QtMfcFacade::startDevicesConfigurationWizard(HWND hWnd)
{
    QWinWidget* win = new QWinWidget( hWnd );
    win->showCentered();
    DevicesConfigurationWizard *devicesConfigurationWizardUI = new DevicesConfigurationWizard(win);
    devicesConfigurationWizardUI->setModal(true);
    devicesConfigurationWizardUI->show();
}
```

THe following is my QWizard class :

```
DevicesConfigurationWizard::DevicesConfigurationWizard(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QWizard(parent, flags),
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    this->setWindowFlags( ( (this->windowFlags() | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint)
                       & ~Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint) );
    this->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true );
    connect(this, SIGNAL(currentIdChanged(int)), this, SLOT(onClick(int)));
}

void DevicesConfigurationWizard::onClick(int pageId)
{
    if (m_currentPageId < pageId)
    {        
        //user clicked next button.
        switch (pageId)
        {
            case PAGE_NUMBER_SINGLE_USER:
            {
                setupSingleUserPage();
                break;
            }
            default :
            {
                //problem!!!
            }
        }
        m_currentPageId = pageId;
    }
}

void DevicesConfigurationWizard::onRadioButtonClick()
{
    this->button(this->NextButton)->setEnabled(true);
    this->button(this->FinishButton)->setEnabled(true);
}

void DevicesConfigurationWizard::setupSingleUserPage()
{
    this->button(this->NextButton)->setEnabled(false);
    int newPositionY = 0;
        QVBoxLayout* layout = ui.wpSINGLE_USER->findChild<QVBoxLayout*>("verticalLayout");
        for (vector<Events::VCS::PnPDevice>::const_iterator it=m_devices.begin(); it!=m_devices.end(); it++)
        {
            if (it->type == Events::VCS::HEADSET)
            {
                //add a radio button
                stringstream text;
                text <<  (it->name) << " " << (it->serialNumber) ;
                QRadioButton* radioButton = new QRadioButton(this->ui.wpSINGLE_USER);
                radioButton->setGeometry(X, Y + newPositionY, WIDHT, HEIGHT);
                radioButton->setText(text.str().c_str());
                radioButton->setIconSize(QSize(HEIGHT,HEIGHT));
                newPositionY = newPositionY + HEIGHT;
                layout->insertWidget(0, radioButton);
                connect(radioButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onRadioButtonClick()));
            }
    }
}
```

**EDIT trying to force update does not resolved problem so far**

```
void DevicesConfigurationWizard::onRadioButtonClick()
{
    this->button(this->NextButton)->setEnabled(true);
    this->button(this->FinishButton)->setEnabled(true);
    QWidget::update();
    this->update();
    this->button(this->NextButton)->update();
    QList<QRadioButton*> listButton = ui.wpSINGLE_USER->findChildren<QRadioButton*>();
    listButton[0]->update();
    listButton[1]->update();
    QApplication::processEvents();
}
```

Comment: it should be no problem. `show()` is just the call, when you do not want the window to be modal. the screenshots are nice, but i would like some of your code ...

Comment: @Zaiborg Code has been added.  I feel that the problem might be that the main application is Mfc.  I did a quick test with QtCreator and your are right, `show()` is not a problem.  But like I said in the above example, using exec resolved the problem (but it brings a new problem, where I am bloking my Mfc application )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is comming from my Mfc application.  A timer was sending a timer event to the event loop every 100 miliseconds, so, my Qt application was not able to update properly.  So, what I did, I added QCoreApplication::processEvents() into OnTimer, on Mfc application.

This way, QCoreApplication::processEvents is being call every 100 milisedonds and my Qt UI is now correctly updated.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help:

```
void DevicesConfigurationWizard::setupSingleUserPage()
{
    this->button(this->NextButton)->setEnabled(false);
    int newPositionY = 0;
        QVBoxLayout* layout = ui.wpSINGLE_USER->findChild<QVBoxLayout*>("verticalLayout");
        QButtonGroup* group = new QButtonGroup(this); // add this
        for (vector<Events::VCS::PnPDevice>::const_iterator it=m_devices.begin(); it!=m_devices.end(); it++)
        {
            if (it->type == Events::VCS::HEADSET)
            {
                //add a radio button
                stringstream text;
                text <<  (it->name) << " " << (it->serialNumber) ;
                QRadioButton* radioButton = new QRadioButton(this->ui.wpSINGLE_USER);
                group->addButton(radioButton); // and add this
                radioButton->setGeometry(X, Y + newPositionY, WIDHT, HEIGHT);
                radioButton->setText(text.str().c_str());
                radioButton->setIconSize(QSize(HEIGHT,HEIGHT));
                newPositionY = newPositionY + HEIGHT;
                layout->insertWidget(0, radioButton);
                connect(radioButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onRadioButtonClick()));
            }
    }
}
```

Got a similar problem when i tried to insert radio buttons in a context menu.

soo long zai

Comment: Unfortunately, this does't resolved by problem.  Moreover, the problem is not only with QRadioButton but with QPushButton ("Next" button not being updated).  Thx for the help

Comment: use explicit call of `QWidget::update()`? may not be the sexiest way, but you could try to fit it in when the radio button gets clicked...

Comment: Neither :(  See my updated post, I tried all possible ways to force an update.  I really really don't understand :/